# Changing speed of all items in an ArrayList from ChangeListener method

Tags: java, jframe

I'm new to java and I'm seeking some help. The problem I have is that I cannot change a speed variable in a different class, from within the main class.

I have setter/getter methods, but the problem i am having is deciding which "object" to address to the setter/getter methods.

The slider is meant to change the speed of all of the turtles in the ArrayList. If i could have some help with this that would be great. Aside from the speed changing, the rest of the ChangeListener method works.

Main Class:

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

class TurtleProgram
{
 private JFrame frame;
 private Canvas canvas;
 private JPanel lowerPanel;
 private JButton addTurtleButton;
 private ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles;
 private JSlider turtleSpeed;
 private int oldSliderState = 100;
 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  new TurtleProgram();
 }

 public TurtleProgram()
 {
  frame = new JFrame();
  canvas = new Canvas();
  lowerPanel = new JPanel();
  lowerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  DynamicTurtle referenceTurtle = new DynamicTurtle(canvas , new CartesianCoordinate(400,300));
  
  turtles = new ArrayList<DynamicTurtle>();
  turtles.add(new RandomTurtleB(canvas, 400, 300));  

  addTurtleButton = new JButton("Add A Turtle?");
  lowerPanel.add(addTurtleButton);

  turtleSpeed = new JSlider(0, 100, 100);
  lowerPanel.add(turtleSpeed);

  frame.setTitle("Welcome to Button Simulator!");
  frame.setSize(800, 600);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
  frame.setVisible(true);  
  frame.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  frame.add(canvas);

  addTurtleButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
  {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
   {
    turtles.add(new RandomTurtleB(canvas, 400, 300));
   }
  } );

  turtleSpeed.addChangeListener( new ChangeListener()
  {
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) 
   {
    int currentSliderState = turtleSpeed.getValue();
    int currentSpeed = (turtles.get(i)).getSpeed(); //HERE I CANNOT USE THE TURTLES IN THE ARRAYLIST TO SET SPEED

    if(currentSliderState < oldSliderState)
    {
     System.out.println("is less");
     (turtles.get(i)).setSpeed(currentSpeed - 100); //DECREASES ALL TURTLES SPEED
    }

    else if(currentSliderState > oldSliderState)
    {
     System.out.println("is more");
     (turtles.get(i)).setSpeed(currentSpeed + 100); //INCREASES ALL TURTLES SPEED
    }

    oldSliderState = (turtles.get(i)).getValue();    
   }
  } );  

  gameLoop();
 }

 private void gameLoop() 
 {
  int deltaTime = 20;
  
  while(true)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).unDrawTurtle();    
    (turtles.get(i)).wrapPosition((turtles.get(i)).getPositionX(), (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY());
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).update(1000); 
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).drawTurtle();    
   }
  
  Utils.pause(deltaTime/2);
  } 
 } 
}
```

The class containing the setter/getter methods:

```js
class DynamicTurtle extends Turtle
{
 private int speed = 100;
 private int time;
 private double xPos, yPos;
 private CartesianCoordinate myLocation;
 private int Angle = 0;

 DynamicTurtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation)
 {
  super(canvas, initLocation);  
 }

 DynamicTurtle(Canvas canvas, double xPosition, double yPosition) //THE PROBLEM CONSTRUCTOR 
 {
  super(canvas, new CartesianCoordinate(xPosition, yPosition));  
 }

 public int getSpeed()
 {
  return this.speed;
 }

 public void setSpeed(int speed)
 {
  this.speed = speed;
 }

 public void update(int time)
 {
  this.move((speed*100/time)); 
  canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
 }
}
```

Thankyou for your help in advance, I have not removed code(I'm aware it's long) from the Main so you can see my logic in how i approached dealing with ArrayLists in the main. I am aware i cannot use this "get(i)". Cheers.

Comment: Do all turtles have the same speed?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Hello there, Yes. Within the DynamicTurtle Class all turtles have the same speed, and the speed variable is only used in the update() method.

Comment: If all turtles will always move at the same speed, you can make the speed variable `static`.

Answer (score 0):

From inside the `ChangeListener` class, you can access that `turtles` variable with `TurtleProgram.this.turtles`.  `TurtleProgram.this` gets you the enclosing instance of `TurtleProgram` in which the `ChangeListener` was constructed.

But, as Saviour Self suggested in his comment, if different turtles will never have the same speed, just make the speed variable, along with its get/set methods, static.